# Vertically and horizontally align image inside table

Tags: tables, graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a table with two columns. The first column contains text, the second a image. Short example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{tab:mytab}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1.0cm}|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Number}   & \textbf{Images} \\ \hline
        Nr. 1 & \raisebox{.5\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{foo}}       \\ \hline
        Nr. 2 & \raisebox{.5\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{foo}}       \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I want to center the text and image vertically and horizontally. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You left off the minus, `\raisebox{-.5\totalheight}{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help of package `adjustbox` you can obtain:

[image]

In the first row the margin above and below picture is added, in the second row the image is without added margins. The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{tab:mytab}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|c|}
        \hline
\textbf{Number}   
        &   \textbf{Images} \\ 
        \hline
Nr. 1   &   \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,
                             margin=0pt 1ex 0pt 1ex,valign=m]{example-image}  \\
        \hline
Nr. 2   &   \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,valign=m]{example-image}  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** If you like to have horizontally centered contents also in the first table's column, than the following changes are necessary:

- in preamble to be add `\usepackage{array}`
- in table parameters the column type `p{...}` should be replaced by `>{\centering}p{...}`

Answer (score 2):

In the provided example, a minus sign was left off the length `.5\totalheight`.  Graphical images are set above the baseline, when using `\includegraphics`, whereas `tabular` cells are centered.  Thus, one must move the graphical image **down** by half its height to compensate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{tab:mytab}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1.0cm}|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Number}   & \textbf{Images} \\ \hline
        Nr. 1 & \raisebox{-.5\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}}       \\ \hline
        Nr. 2 & \raisebox{-.5\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}}       \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To get *even more precise* centering, the downward shift of the image should be compensated by 1/2 the height of a line of text, thus, the shift should proceed as `\raisebox{-.5\dimexpr\totalheight-\ht\strutbox}{...}`.

Note I also widened the first column to `1.3cm`, so as to allow the word `Number` to fit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{tab:mytab}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1.3cm}|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Number}   & \textbf{Images} \\ \hline
        Nr. 1 & \raisebox{-.5\dimexpr\totalheight-\ht\strutbox}{%
          \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}}       \\ \hline
        Nr. 2 & \raisebox{-.5\dimexpr\totalheight-\ht\strutbox}{%
          \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}}\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]